# How do you describe a forceful movement of a small object?

Tags: word-request

If, for example, a fragment of an explosive device flies with force and pierces a human or an object, what do you call that forceful movement?

> a fragment [flew with great force] into [something]

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking here, but the term for fragments of an explosive device is [shrapnel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shrapnel), or "a piece of shrapnel" (since **shrapnel** is uncountable).

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of words or phrases that might be used here:

- "a fragment careened into the soldier's body"
- "a fragment crashed into the soldier's body"
- "a fragment shot into the soldier's body"